# Cannot click on toggle with selenium because of ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automation

I am trying to click a toggle with Selenium Webdriver and Python but get the following exception:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
                           (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)
```

My HTML code

```html
<div _ngcontent-c7="" class="form-group">
  <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="opened">Opened</label>
 <div _ngcontent-c7="" class="toggle-switch">
    <input _ngcontent-c7="" id="opened" name="opened" type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <label _ngcontent-c7="" for="opened"></label>
 </div>
 <span _ngcontent-c7="" class="form-control-helper">Toggle text description.</span>
</div>
```

I use the following selector and it is 100% unique:

```
.toggle-switch>label[for=opened]
```

What can be the issue? This is the `Angular` modal dialog.
I tried many unique locators, both `XPATH` and `CSS` and I am sure this is not a locator problem.
Did someone else had a similar problem?

My Python code:

```
    toggle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".toggle-switch>label[for=opened]")
    toggle.click()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you're trying to interact with the label. you want the input element:

```
 #remove the label from page
 driver.execute_script("document.querySelector(\"strong[for='opened']\").style.visibility = 'hidden';")

 toggle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#opened")
 toggle.click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it but got the error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input _ngcontent-c6="" id="opened" name="opened" type="checkbox" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"> is not clickable at point (621, 448). Other element would receive the click: <label _ngcontent-c6="" for="opened"></label>
                               (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.111)

Comment: I added debug("Element is visible? " + str(toggle.is_displayed())) and see False. It means  the element is not found by selenium.

Comment: ahh the label is styled to overlay the input some how. Ok.

Comment: I updated to remove the label overlay. A Pain, but may be neccesary.

Comment: I tried it, but got an error (I also added escape characters). SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'document.querySelector("strong[for='opened']").style.visibility = "hidden";' is not a valid XPath expression.
Maybe click with Javascript is the main option here. I will investigate later.

Comment: I messed up my strings.

Comment: If the last hope is using Javascript, I think the better solution will be. "driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", toggle)"                                      But I am will try your approach also.

Answer (score 1):

The best bulletproof option which I use now is:

```
toggle = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".toggle-switch>label[for=opened]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", toggle)
```

In addition, sometimes I need to wait until an element that covers my toggle becomes not visible with:

```
 wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "my css selector")))
```