# ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable C# Nunit Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors, nunit, webdriverwait

I am new to Selenium C# Nunit.
I ran following line of codes

```
 IWebElement SplitCase = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='OpportunityPageV2UsrSplitCase503e4272-cdbd-44d2-98c2-e67a2996c717ComboBoxEdit-el']"));
 SplitCase.Click();
        
 IWebElement SplitCaseYes = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[data-item-marker=Yes]"));
```

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));

```
 SplitCaseYes.Click();
```

I got following Message:
Message:
OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
Stack Trace:
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebElement.Click()
TestClass1.CaseInfoTab() line 151

Then I add 10 seconds of wait :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("li[data-item-marker=Yes]")));
```

I got this message:

Message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds
```

Stack Trace:
DefaultWait`1.ThrowTimeoutException(String exceptionMessage, Exception lastException) DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
TestClass1.CaseInfoTab() line 150

Please see attachment as well

Thank you for your help
NG

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you clarify what you're trying to do and what is going wrong? Also what have you already tried to fix it?

Comment: `.//*[@id='OpportunityPageV2UsrSplitCase503e4272-cdbd-44d2-98c2-e67a2996c717ComboBoxEdit-el'] `- this is the problem. Add his element html code

Comment: HI Vitallis                                                                                                                           
,I believe problem is with this code of line.  SplitCaseYes.Click();                                                      For this one I have been gettingthies message;  ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable.                                                         
RemoteWebElement.Click()

Comment: Can you please add as much data as possible to the question: link to site (if you are allowed), steps you execute and on which line of code you receive the error. Having this info will have to identify the problem more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector seems to be wrong.Try now. It should be `tagname[attributename='attributeval']`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("li[data-item-marker='Yes']")));
```

---

Or Use following xpath.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//li[@data-item-marker='Yes' and text()='Yes']")));
```

**Update**:

Try with Java script executor.

```
IWebElement SplitCaseYes = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("li[data-item-marker='Yes']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", SplitCaseYes);
```

Comment: Hi KunduK                                                                                                                                                 I tried with your code of line, and  got this message:

Message:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds

Comment: @user15574820 : it seems element is not visible on the page. try with JavaScript executor to click. try updated one and let me know.

Comment: KunduK--- I did try with JavaScript but no luck . Got this message:                    
     Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Click()
    TestClass1.CaseInfoTab() line 156

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
IWebElement SplitCase = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='OpportunityPageV2UsrSplitCase503e4272-cdbd-44d2-98c2-e67a2996c717ComboBoxEdit-el']"));
```

to

```
IWebElement SplitCase = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@id,'OpportunityPageV2UsrSplitCase')]"));
```

I am not sure if there is `div` In the beginning. I do not see it on the screenshot. Verify it.
The locator that you use is not stable.
Also add explicit waits.

**Try 2:**

For `SplitCaseYes` also try using this css selector: `By.CssSelector('li[data-item-marker="Yes"]')` or `ul>li[data-item-marker=Yes]` or their variations.

Also, add wait **before** clicking your element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(PropertiesCollection.driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("your selector")));
el.click();
```

**Possible Ajax problem**

There is a probability that your element is not interactable because of Ajax requests:

Try this before clicking as well:

```
public void WaitForAjax()
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
}
```

**Update 4.**
There is a probability that locator above is not unique (did you check CSS locators I proposed?)
Try the following `xpath`:

```
//div[contains(@data-item-marker,'Split Case')]/ul/li[@data-item-marker='Yes']
```

This locator first looks at `data-item-marker` with Split Case text, then goes level down to `ul`, and finally to the second `li` element.
In this case instead of `/li[@data-item-marker='Yes']` it's possible to use just `li[2]`

Before executing any code with locators, you should check if it's unique.

[image]

**Update 5:**
I found out that C#'s Selenium ExpectedConditions is obsolete: [C# Selenium 'ExpectedConditions is obsolete'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49866334/c-sharp-selenium-expectedconditions-is-obsolete)
Try using: `SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions`. You'll need to import it with Nuget package manager. Here is the example:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("ul>li[data-item-marker=Yes]")));
```

Comment: Hi Vitallis ,I believe problem is with this code of line. SplitCaseYes.Click(); For this one I have been getting this message; ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable. RemoteWebElement.Click() –

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: Vitallis-- as suggested I did try with this code:                                                                        
 IWebElement SplitCaseYes = driver.FindElement( By.CssSelector("ul>li[data-item-marker='Yes']")); IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", SplitCaseYes);                                        
  SplitCaseYes.Click();                                                                                             
  I got OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable

Comment: Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Click()

Comment: OK. I'll update the answer with more suggestions

Comment: Thank you so much for your support 

Comment: Hi Vitallis, I will update you about result soon. Actually our environment  is down since Saturday, our team is working on it.

Comment: Hi Vitaliis I did try and got this message: Message: 
    OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotInteractableException : element not interactable
      (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)
  Stack Trace: 
    RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
    RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    RemoteWebElement.Click()
    TestClass1.CaseInfoTab() line 163

Comment: I did use following code of lines:  IWebElement SplitCaseYes = driver.FindElement( By.CssSelector("ul>li[data-item-marker='Yes']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", SplitCaseYes); var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
  wait.Until(d => (bool)(d as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
  SplitCaseYes.Click();

Comment: @vitallis do you have any other suggestion or remark ?

Comment: I'll try to check it later today? What is the status? Looks like a long issue

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558779/cannot-click-on-toggle-with-selenium-because-of-elementnotinteractableexception this is for Python but is applicable to any language and always workds for me. I don't know why someone downvoted it yesterday. You can update it)

Comment: Thanks Vitaliis, I will try this piece of codes and let you know the results.

Comment: FYI I have voted to your answer:) As you always try to help others. May God bless you.

Comment: You are welcome. Which answer? I'll try to check your problem today again.

Comment: If you want to upvote an answer, you should click ^ (up) arrow, not down :)

Comment: I did clicks on up arrow, I believe. Anyways I clicks on up arrow again :)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add more details to the question if it's possible?

Comment: I'll return to your question later today.

Comment: I have added one more image, let me know what other info I can provide you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231179/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-shikha).

Answer (score 0):

As for the problem I had, the issue was that there were two elements on the page with the same ID, the first of which was not clickable. So after calling the click method, the error "element not interactable" would occur.

**Solution :**

After changing the ID of the elements, my problem was solved.

**More explanation :**

With the following html fragment, the command `driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn1")).Click();` An error is encountered :

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1" style="display:none">first button with id "btn1"</button>
<button type="button" id="btn1" >second button with id "btn1"</button>
```

But there will be no problem in the following html fragment :

```html
<button type="button" id="btn0" style="display:none">button with id "btn0"</button>
<button type="button" id="btn1" >button with id "btn1"</button>
```

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: dear @AztecCodes : The html code is placed in the response text. Do you like something else?