# How to make selenium click on a radio button

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to use Selenium in Python 3.9 to click on a button.

https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card
[image]

I want to click on Effective Date and click on July 2021 then click ok.

The first two was working, then I added the code to click the OK button and I can no longer click on July 2021. Interesting the click OK step also works.

Error I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

I have tried:

1. sleep statement to make it wait for the button to become available
2. Web Driver wait
3. Action Chain to make it scroll into view

I am using Selenium IDE with chrome to give me the css tags.

```
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def print_hi():


    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


    annual_pass = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")

    type = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('.form-list:nth-child(2) > li:nth-child(1) .form-label')
    type.click()

    annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")
    open_eff_date_panel = annual_pass.find_element_by_link_text('Select')
    open_eff_date_panel.click()

    annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")
    selectJuly = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('li:nth-child(3) .form-label')
    #selectJuly = annual_pass.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="date2"]')
    selectJuly.click() ## error here##

    annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")
    ok_button = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('#reserver-date .bouton')
    ok_button.click()

    sleep(10)
    annual_pass.close() 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking toggles may be unstable with Selenium.

First, try this approach:

```
selectJuly = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('#reserver .panel.is-active>.panel-middle li:nth-child(3) .form-label')
annual_pass.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selectJuly)
ok_button = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('#reserver-date .bouton')
ok_button.click()
```

It works, but I do not like that the window is not completely rolled out.

Full code with debugging info left:

```
import time
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def print_hi():


    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    chrome_options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


    annual_pass = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
    annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")

    open_eff_date_panel = annual_pass.find_element_by_link_text('Select')
    open_eff_date_panel.click()
    # wait = WebDriverWait(open_eff_date_panel, 10)
    # wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    #     (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "//html[@class='js history es5array video opacity csspointerevents placeholder inlinesvg es5date supports es5function es5object strictmode es5string json es5syntax es5undefined es5 no-touchevents cssvhunit mediaqueries vibrate csscolumns csscolumns-width csscolumns-span csscolumns-fill csscolumns-gap csscolumns-rule csscolumns-rulecolor csscolumns-rulestyle csscolumns-rulewidth csscolumns-breakbefore csscolumns-breakafter csscolumns-breakinside flexbox csstransforms csstransforms3d no-ios panel-active']")))
    selectJuly = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector(
        '#reserver .panel.is-active>.panel-middle li:nth-child(3) .form-label')
    annual_pass.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", selectJuly)
    ok_button = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('#reserver-date .bouton')
    ok_button.click()

    # annual_pass.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi()
```

2 Also, you can try implementing your own function to wait till some css property of your form is changed (for example width). For this use Selenium's `value_of_css_property`.

3
If you wait for all classes to become available in xpath, it will also work, but does not look robust. You can change this locator into css and exclude classes one by one to make it shorter. Waiting just for `panel-active` class won't work:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(open_eff_date_panel, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//html[@class='js history es5array video opacity csspointerevents placeholder inlinesvg es5date supports es5function es5object strictmode es5string json es5syntax es5undefined es5 no-touchevents cssvhunit mediaqueries vibrate csscolumns csscolumns-width csscolumns-span csscolumns-fill csscolumns-gap csscolumns-rule csscolumns-rulecolor csscolumns-rulestyle csscolumns-rulewidth csscolumns-breakbefore csscolumns-breakafter csscolumns-breakinside flexbox csstransforms csstransforms3d no-ios panel-active']")))
selectJuly = annual_pass.find_element_by_css_selector('#reserver .panel.is-active>.panel-middle li:nth-child(3) .form-label')
selectJuly.click()
```

I tried as well, `wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))` but it did not work for this case.

I had a similar question: [Cannot click on toggle with selenium because of ElementNotInteractableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558779/cannot-click-on-toggle-with-selenium-because-of-elementnotinteractableexception)

Comment: thx weirdly the execute_script and the css didn't work, what worked is removing the annual_pass.get before selectJuly: 

     #annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")

Comment: Funny, when I executed the code it did not always work with this annual_pass.get() removed. I did not consider it at all as I thought that you just pasted the code wrong. SO what I suggest is removing other `annual_pass.get("https://www.sepaq.com/en/reservation/national-parks/annual-card")` as you open the site once and work with this link.

Comment: When i was researching this I came across a post about how the issue was the DOM had changed as you click through the page so the new get would refresh the DOM. but this method seems to be really unstable because now the click july started failing again

Comment: lol it was working, now it stopped and i don't know why...

Comment: Check updated answer and accept/ upvote it it works)

Comment: does chrome webdriver for selenium clear the cache each time I run the script?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232817/discussion-between-vitaliis-and-d-zou).